# When publishing to shinyapps.io, Error: cannot open the connection

Tags: shiny

I am attempting to update a Shiny App that I last modified in April, 
     https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/StatusGraphsApp/StatusReportInteractive.Rmd

The updated app runs fine in RStudio, but when I go to publish it, a couple things happen.  I get an error on the page, `Error: cannot open the connection` and it is assigned a different url than before, 
     https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/StatusReportInteractive

I have not introduced any new files, simply modified the old ones.

1. How can I successfully publish the updated version to shinyapps.io?
2. How can I get it to use the same url I had before?

I am using R version 3.2.2, RStudio version 0.99.467, and Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 m in Windows 7.  [*I also sent this question to shinyapps@rstudio.com.*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that that behavior of the RStudio IDE changed with 0.99 release. When you click the publish for an RMarkdown doc, you are now prompted with a list of files to publish. By default only the RMarkdown document will be deployed. If you have additional data files that are required, you will need to include those by clicking 'Add more'.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.  Everything is working and the url is named how I want it, too.  https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/SeaLampreyStatus